# Adding class attribute to HTML Tag in TYPO3 9.x or access the config.yaml configuration in typoscript?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

In my TYPO3 9.5 LTS project i want the follwoing HTML Tag rendered:

```
<html dir="ltr" lang="de" class="no-js">
```

In previous TYPO3 Settings, i could configure this by the typoscript:

```
page.config.htmlTag_setParams = dir="ltr" lang="{$config.language}" class="no-js"
```

But in TYPO3 9.5, the language settings are defined in the config.yaml file. Without the typoscript setting above, the html tag will render the correct dir attribute and lang attributt. But if i try to add the class attribute like this:

```
page.config.htmlTag_setParams = class="no-js"
```

the lang and dir attribute will be overwritten.
Is there a way to just add the class attribute without removing the lang and dir attribute?
Can i access the yaml configurations in typoscript setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be possible as soon as 9.5.2 has been released because of the feature https://review.typo3.org/#/c/58976/